# bind form validation to a component outside the current component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

i create a `searchable-dropdown` components and i need to use it in many components , now i have a problem for bind vlaidation of form to this components .

for example i have a from for create a user and i need bind validation of one field to `searchable-dropdown` components .

```
private createForm(): void {
    this.courseAddForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        name: ['', [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.maxLength(this.val.maxLen.title)
        ]],
        roleId: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    });

}
```

i need to bind `roleId` Validation in this components :

```
<div class="col-lg-6 kt-margin-bottom-20-mobile">
    <kt-searchable-dropdown [formGroup]="courseAddForm" [formcontrolName]="'roleId'"
            (selectedId)="selectedCourse($event)" [formTitle]="'COURSE.COURSE_GROUP'">
     </kt-searchable-dropdown>
 </div>
```

i try this code for find vlaidation of this form for `roleId` but its not work for me :

```
@Input() url: string;
@Input() formTitle: string;
@Input() ItemId: number;
@Input() formcontrolName: string;
@Input() formGroup: FormGroup;
@Input() control: FormControl;
@Output() selectedId = new EventEmitter<number>();

fieldErrors(field: string): any {
    let controlState = this.formGroup.controls[field];
    return (controlState.dirty || controlState.touched) ? controlState.errors : null;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
    <div class="col-lg-12 mt-4 kt-margin-bottom-20-mobile">
            <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid" appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>{{'GENERAL.TITLE' | translate}} *</mat-label>
                <input [formControlName]="formcontrolName" (keyup)="getValues($event.target.value)" matInput
                    [placeholder]="'GENERAL.TITLE' | translate">
                <span *ngIf="fieldErrors(formcontrolName)" class="text-right">
                    <label *ngIf="fieldErrors(formcontrolName).required">WORKED</label>
                </span>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

**How can i Solve this Problem ????**

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a CustomValueAccessor inside this searchable-dropdown component.

For example, a custom file component able to be used on reactive forms:

```
@Component({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: FileUploadComponent,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class FileUploadComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() progress;
  onChange: Function;
  private file: File | null = null;

  @HostListener('change', ['$event.target.files']) emitFiles( event: FileList ) {
    const file = event && event.item(0);
    this.onChange(file);
    this.file = file;
  }

  constructor( private host: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement> ) {
  }

  writeValue( value: null ) {
    // clear file input
    this.host.nativeElement.value = '';
    this.file = null;
  }

  registerOnChange( fn: Function ) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched( fn: Function ) {
  }

}
```

[Here is a detailed blog post](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/) about what you need to do.